# Root of order k

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Im trying to show that a number $x_0$ a root of order $k$ of the polynomial $p(x)$ if and only if $p(x_0)=p^{'}(x_0)= ... =p^{(k-1)}(x_0)=0$ and $p^k(x_0)\neq0$.

Is there an easy way to do this using the Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You only need to expand $p(x)$ around $x=x_0$, i.e.,
$$
p(x)=p(x_0)+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{p^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{p^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i
$$
where $n$ is the degree of $p$.

On the other hands, you have
$$
p(x)=(x-x_0)^kq(x)
$$
for some polynomial $q$.
It follows that $p^{(i)}(x_0)=0$ for all $i<k$ but $p^{(k)}(x_0)\neq 0.$